# how to set python env in org mode

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

When I write some python code in emacs org-mode, how can I set the python env to a specific env. I use the code as follow but it didn't work.

```
    #+BEGIN_SRC python :python /opt/local/bin/python2.7 :results output
    print "python 2"
    #+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 3):

You could go to the scratch buffer and execute `(setq org-babel-python-command "python2")`

Then in an org file try

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
import platform
return platform.python_version()
#+END_SRC
```

And should get something like:

```
#+RESULTS:
: 2.7.13
```

If that works then add it to your init file.

Comment: I use anaconda to manage different python version, I want to specify a python interpreter. For example, I install some packages in one version, if I use your solution, I may get  the "import error" when I import those packages. The only way I can think of is to activate one python env and then start up emacs in shell. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed org-mode to run python from one of my anaconda environments. You can set the emacs variable, python-shell-virtualenv-root, to the anaconda environment's path. That is;

`M-x customize-variable RET`

`python-shell-virtualenv-root RET`

Click on the Value Menu button where you can then type in the box

String:`/PATH/TO/VIRTUALENV`

That solved it for me.

EDIT:
I failed to mention the above was tested only on emacs 25.2 
Additionally, I now realize the solution works only in session code blocks. If a session is not specified, then the python code is run with the default, system-wide, Python installation.

Comment: Yes thank you!!! I was struggling with this but I wasn't using sessions. Thank you for adding the EDIT in there